# How to get a page printed with its css intact in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, css, printing, ruby-on-rails-3.2

[image]I am using ruby-on-rails-3.2 app, trying to get print-out of a page but when it gets printed its doesnt have it css. Here is my code

```
   <%= link_to("Print this Page", "#", :onclick =>"PrintElem('.PrintElem','News Details')") %>


    function PrintElem(news_heading, reporters_details, full_news_text, title)
    {
    heading = jQuery('head').html();
    body_data = jQuery('body').html();
    Popup(heading, body_data);
    return true;
    }

    function Popup(news_heading, body_data)
    {//start
    // var mywindow = window.open('','printwindow');
    mywindow = window.open('#','printing','height=900,width=900,scrollbars=1');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>'+heading+'</head><body onload="window.print();">');
    mywindow.document.write(body_data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>')
    mywindow.onload = function() { mywindow.print(); }
    mywindow.document.close();
    return true;
    //end
    }
```

Here problem is that page is printed before loading javascripts and css. This page should be print after all javascript and css is loaded. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does not display in print? Colors? I build a php billing system lately and chrome for example by defaul removes some of the css rules in the print!

Comment: Yes Alen, I want color print.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a document with the css and the javacstcipt basically the

```
<html>
<head>
//Your css
//Your scripts
</head>
<body>
</dody>
</html>
```

Then open

```
window.open('/somefile.html', 'Yout Title maybe from the document', 'width=900');
```

Then use jQuery to populate the dummy print page(body area);

```
$(body).prepend(body_data);
```

Maybe you are not loading the css and javascript correctly while writing all the html after the page is loaded with javascript.

Keep in mind you need some css rules for pages to print correctly (colors, styles)

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact; // For chrome browser
```

Tell me if it works for you!

Comment: Please see screenshot, when i click print-out, it opens like above screenshot. Before loading javascript.

Comment: I see but why create another html and populate it with the data from the old page when you can have a button to open window.print and style whatt you want to show and what you dont want to show with the @ media print{} hide all menus and elements of the document that you dont want to print out with display none inside the @ media